# Google spreadsheets only shows 6 fonts for me?

Tags: google-sheets

Reading around various sites online it seems like you can use any number of Google's web fonts on their Spreadsheets web app, however I only have 6 listed:

[image: screen shot]

I've noticed some people have had the option to add more fonts suddenly appear when they change their language to English, but mine is already set to that (UK) and after changing it to English (US) I still don't get the option for more fonts.

Any ideas why this could be please? I'm using the 'new' spreadsheets too.

Comment: What is the source for "... it seems like you can use any number of Google's web fonts on their Spreadsheets web app"? I have never seen that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, only Documents and Presentations have the capability for adding more fonts. Spreadsheets seems to be limited (at least for now) to the six listed. (I see several threads on the Google Product forums complaining about this.)

One thing that seems to have worked for some people is to upload a spreadsheet in a different format (e.g., Microsoft Excel) with the desired font and convert it to a Google Spreadsheet. From what they report the font is retained. How useful that would be for new information added to the spreadsheet remains to be seen.

Comment: Ah! This would make sense... thank you! To be honest I use spreadsheets almost daily, but have never used the other apps, I didn't realise they differed like this.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the cell from another worksheet (perhaps a converted Excel file) where you have the desired font and paste it into the new document. You can see the font is copied. 
Now copy the layout (font) to the desired cells.